# XMLReader giving a timeout when opening external XML

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, timeout, xml

I'm having a timeout when trying to open an external XML (which exists, I can see it in the browser when placing the direct link).

I am sure XMLReader is installed and on, and it works if calling a local XML (tested and works as expected).

But when trying to get the same XML from an external source (another domain) I get this (domains and IPs masked here):

```
[Mon May 12 20:03:44 2014] [error] [client xxxxxx] PHP Warning:  XMLReader::open(http://myotherdomain/data.xml): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /var/www/html/mysite/xmlreader.php on line 29
[Mon May 12 20:03:44 2014] [error] [client xxxxxx] PHP Warning:  XMLReader::open(): Unable to open source data in /var/www/html/mysite/xmlreader.php on line 29
```

Line 29 refers to the `open()`:

```
if (!$reader->open("http://myotherdomain/data.xml"))
```

My server is a CentOS 6.5, Apache 2.2.15, PHP 5.4.25

**What is wrong here?, why am I getting a timeout?** (this happens with every external XML that I have tried)

Comment: can you try to SSH into servers and issue `wget` or `curl` to download file? Just to test connectivity. Other than that, this is too "XMLReader" specific, as we have no idea what `open()` really does (does it use curl, fsockopen, file_get_contents or something else to fetch the XML?)

Comment: @edvinas.me thanks for the suggestions, it helped me pin point the problem, it was related to the firewall after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, it was related to the firewall port 80…

It didn't allow connections from the server to the exterior, so not related to XMLReader after all, and another firewall related issue.